# Cómo evitar repetir el código

Tags: css, html5, svg

estoy modificando un sitio diseñado por otra persona.
Cada ítem del menú está escrito de la siguiente forma

```
<li><a href="[pagina]"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" class="icon icon-pos-left svg-secondary"><path d="m11 12v-8l-5 4z" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 17 0)"></path></svg>PAGINA</a></li>
```

así repetido por cada ítem del menú.

Quisiera encontrar una forma de mostrar el svg desde un archivo externo, que quede algo asi:

```
<li><svg src=...><a href=...>
```

Sé que así como lo puse no se puede, pero seguramente hay una alternativa que evite tener que escribir lo mismo 50 veces. Me podrían indicar como? Gracias

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y re orienta tu pregunta a una duda mas clara y fácil de reproducir

Comment: Gracias, editado

Answer (score 0):

como estas?

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, lo que quieres hacer es llamar al svg externamente no ?.

Puedes usar el tag img que ya soporta svg externos.

Por ejemplo:

```
<img src="kiwi.svg" alt="Kiwi standing on oval">
```

Entonces en tu ejemplo podes hacer lo siguiente:

**Archivo "logo.svg"**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" class="icon icon-pos-left svg-secondary"><path d="m11 12v-8l-5 4z" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 17 0)"></path></svg>
```

**HTML**

```
<li>
  <a href="[pagina]">
   <img src="logo.svg" alt="logo"> PAGINA
  </a>
</li>
```

Espero que sea de ayuda. Suerte!

Comment: Gracias Facundo, esto también funciona, seguramente habrá pros y contras respecto a la respuesta anterior.

Answer (score 0):

En SVG el elemento `<use>` esta hecho exactamente para algo así.

Primero guardas todos tus iconos en los `<defs>`de un elemento svg que puedes poner al principio del `<body>` o justo antes del cierre, o donde tu quiras. Este elemento svg no es visible así que no estorba en la página.

`#root{width:0;height:0;position:absolute;left:-100em}`

**Importante**: los trazados que quieres reutilizar tienen que tener un `id`, en este caso `id="flecha"`

En el menú reutilizas, tantas veces como quieras, la flecha de esta manera:

`<use xlink:href="#flecha" />`

La ventaja de este método es que, si lo necesitas, puedes cambiar el color de los íconos así:

`<use xlink:href="#flecha" fill="red" />`

o en el css:

`.icon{fill:red}`

A continuación una demo. Espero que sea lo que necesites:

```css
#root{width:0;height:0;position:absolute;left:-100em}

.icon.icon-pos-left.svg-secondary{fill:red}
```

```html
<svg id="root" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<defs>
<path id="flecha" d="m11 12v-8l-5 4z" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 17 0)"></path>
</defs>
</svg>


<ul>
<li><a href="#">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" class="icon icon-pos-left svg-secondary">
    <use xlink:href="#flecha" />
  </svg>PAGINA</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias, había visto esto pero había entendido que xlink:href ya no se usaba. Encontré un tutorial y apliqué tu respuesta pero usando un archivo externo y poniendo toda la definición del svg ahí. Al parecer funciona, sigo probando

Comment: No es que ya no se usa. Puedes dejar de utilizarlo pero puede no funcionar en Safari o navegadores antiguos